# get a string from an array in php 

Tags: php, arrays

```
array
  0 => string 'profile' (length=8)
  1 => string 'helloworld' (length=8)
  2 => string 'string2' (length=7)

// lets say we have an defined string that we want to split it out. or make it disappear.

string 'profile' (length=8)
```

**how can we just get** `helloworld` and `string2` **in an array from the array useing the string we defined ? ( get the a defined string out of the array )
is there a good function for this problem ?**

the result should be like

```
array
  1 => string 'helloworld' (length=8)
  2 => string 'string2' (length=7)
```

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Sorry it is not clear what you are asking, there are functions like in_array, array_search, array_keys and array_values at your disposal that should do what I think you are asking, if not please clarify.

Comment: i just want to split the array above, with the string we defined. and make a new string that have helloworld in it. wait let me edit

Comment: Still confusing. Could you please add some more keys to your main array and make us see what you really want?

Comment: i just want to get a defined string out of the array. what do we call that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$yourDefinedString = "profile";
foreach($yourArray as $myArray){
   if($myArray != $yourDefinedString){
      echo $myArray;
   }
}
```

Some variations possible, depending on how you would handle this array:

```
array
  0 => string 'profile' (length=8)
  1 => string 'helloworld' (length=8)
  2 => string 'anotherString' (length=8)
```

This example would print

```
helloworldanotherString
```

You could add newlins or spaces of course

after your edit:
You could just remove stuff by getting the difference between two arrays? You could even remove more than just one string:

```
$theOffendingStrings = array("yourString");
$result = array_diff($youArray, $theOffendingStrings);
```

Comment: how about turning it back to array ? like the result above, sory ive edited the question clearer. thanks btw.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
$array = array(
    'profile',
    'helloworld',
    'string2'
);

$str = 'profile';

$array = array_flip($array);
unset($array[$str]);
$array = array_flip($array);

// Array
// (
//     [1] => 'helloworld',
//     [2] => 'string2'
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo $var[1]` 
will display hello world, where $var is the variable your are doing var_dump($var) now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) as well:

```
$array    = ['profile', 'helloworld', 'string2'];
$ignore   = 'profile';
$filtered = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function ($i) use ($ignore) {
        return $i !== $ignore;
    }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you’re printing something expecting it to be a string, but the value is actually an array.

So, if it’s going to be an array always, you may print all items comma separated -

```
echo implode(", ", $yourVar);
```

Or, it’s can be an array sometimes, you may concat conditionally-

```
 echo is_array($yourVar)? implode(", ", $yourVar) : $yourVar;
```